# apt-get install/update/upgrade commands inside docker container update kernel or not

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, apt-get

I am running my service in docker container and while building docker images from `Dockerfile` we do `run apt-get install/update/  ...` multiple times. 
I know it does update/upgrade the packages inside container but does it also upgrade kernel by any chance.

Answer (score 2):

no, its not. .there's only one kernel. i.e. hosts. docker images always have only userspace tools. you can emulate a distro using debootstrap,apt-get,yum etc, but they all share same kernel.
[System level Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization)

The image (or anything else that you will run with Docker) is what is generally called *userland*.
Userland is a collection of files (executables, binaries, data...) that communicate with "the outside world" by doing system calls to the kernel.

Comment: But after doing apt-get update i am seeing some packages which seems to be kernel related. please clarify if i am not wrong.            .root@4fef372dc554:/# dpkg -l | grep linux 
ii  libselinux1:amd64                2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                           amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64             3.13.0-139.188                             amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  util-linux                       2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.9                       amd64        Miscellaneous system utilities
root@4fef372dc554:/#